# Nav like triangles with CSS on li elements

Tags: html, css

I have a series of subtabs that I want to make look like [image], except with more space between the items.

I am using psuedo elements and have successfully created a triangle on the right side of the element, but now I want to create an inset triangle on the left side. I have tried to use `:before` and with `right:100%` but it doesn't accomplish anything.

I was thinking I could do something like this, but no matter how I try and place it I can't seem to "cut" out a triangle from the left side....

```
.tabs > ul > li:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 100%;
    border: 1.65em solid #fff;
}
```

When using the above it just cuts out a little chunk from the triangle on the right.

Full [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joshuaohana/khe43rhs/) of the working bits. (make sure you expand the preview to large width to actually see it in action)

```
.tabs {
    padding-top: 0.5em;
    padding-bottom: 1em;
    padding-right: 40px;
}

.tabs > ul {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.tabs > ul > li {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    background: #eeeeee;
    padding: 1em;
    line-height: 1.25em;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.tabs > ul > li > a {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: Lato-Regular;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

.tabs > ul > li:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    border: 1.65em solid transparent;
}
```

**Update**
Per Aaron's suggestion below I tried playing with z-index to get the before element to work. It looks like it's a step in the right direction but not wholly working yet. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joshuaohana/vy7shxps/)

1) It's not all the way to the left
2) It's a rectangle instead of a triangle

Comment: What kind of browser support to you need to have? I wrote for a site several years ago which required *exactly* the same kind of breadcrumb display as you're doing. We had to support browsers going back to IE7, and I can tell you it was really difficult. Even for IE8 it's not easy. But if you can get away with dropping support for IE7 and IE8, then it becomes a whole lot easier.

Comment: @Simba yes thankfully we only need "modern browser support", so IE10 and newer

Comment: Lucky you!  :)  I see you've accepted a good answer already, so I won't write one of my own, as that's a pretty sound answer, but in case you want another option, I'd also have considered using SVG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `z-index` of the `:after` pseudo to show the angle, then use the before pseudo to create the white section below the main angle.

You may have to fiddle with the height and width of the `:before` to make it wok exactly as you need.

```css
.tabs {
    padding-top: 0.5em;
    padding-bottom: 1em;
    padding-right: 40px;
}

.tabs > ul {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.tabs > ul > li {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    background: #eeeeee;
    padding: 1em 1em 1em 2em;
    line-height: 1.25em;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.tabs > ul > li > a {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: Lato-Regular;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

.tabs > ul > li:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    border: 1.65em solid transparent;
    z-index: 2;
}

.tabs > ul > li:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    top: -3px;
    left: 0;
    border-width: 1.85em 1.65em 1.85em 1.85em;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent #fff;
    z-index: 1;
}

.tabs > ul > li:nth-child(1):after {
  border-left-color: red; }

.tabs > ul > li:nth-child(1) {
  background: red; }

.tabs > ul > li:nth-child(2):after {
  border-left-color: orange; }

.tabs > ul > li:nth-child(2) {
  background: orange; }

.tabs > ul > li:nth-child(3):after {
  border-left-color: gray; }

.tabs > ul > li:nth-child(3) {
  background: gray; }

.tabs > ul > li:nth-child(4):after {
  border-left-color: deepskyblue; }

.tabs > ul > li:nth-child(4) {
  background: deepskyblue; }

.tabs > ul > li:nth-child(5):after {
  border-left-color: blue; }

.tabs > ul > li:nth-child(5) {
  background: blue; }

.tabs > ul > li:nth-child(6):after {
  border-left-color: purple; }

.tabs > ul > li:nth-child(6) {
  background: purple; }

.tabs > ul > li:nth-child(7):after {
  border-left-color: green; }

.tabs > ul > li:nth-child(7) {
  background: green; }
```

```html
<div class="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">Qualification</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Profile</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Skills Assessment</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Interview Prep</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Debrief</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Offer</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Follow Up</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: the snippet you provided does any behave any differently than in my original question. Per your suggestion however, I tried to play with z-index on using both a before and after and couldn't manage to make anything useful. The before keeps showing up as a rectangle instead of a triangle... as in http://jsfiddle.net/joshuaohana/vy7shxps/, which I feel is getting closer

Comment: sorry forgot to add the before pseudo so create the white sections... my bad

Comment: Thanks @Aaron but it still doesn't seem to do anything... when I run your code snippet I see the same as my original question. I tried playing with the z-index as well to no avail. There is still no inset triangle on the left side :(

Comment: ive updated my answer which now contains a before element, this is white and sits below the colored triangle creating the inset.

Comment: Click on **"Run Code Snippet"** below my answer

Comment: When I do Run Code Snippet I still am not seeing the white inset triangle on the left side, see screenshot http://i.imgur.com/59crC5m.png , same with jsfiddle. Sorry if my question wasn't clear but what I want to change is: the left side of each element right now is just a rectangle, and the right is a triangle. I want both left and right to be a triangle. When I view your snippet in a short width it works but if you expand to full screen width the left side is still just a plain vertical line. Make sense?

Comment: Sorry i misunderstood thought you wanted it to sit just below the current angle. Updated my answer once again

Comment: If you would be kind enough to mark my answer as correct, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I did use the @Aaron answer and changed

```
.tabs > ul {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

for

```
.tabs > ul {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: flex-start;
   white-space: nowrap;
}
```

it'll look better when the width changes

here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tinmarin60/khe43rhs/2/)

Comment: Awesome thanks Sergio this is actually 100% what I wanted

Comment: Anytime!...glad to help you